# React showing undefined error that is not viewable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am a student learning about the MERN stack and am working on programming a webpage that has a responsive navigation bar.

I have been watching a video that helps me to achieve this but have stumbled across an issue towards the end.

When I edit my app.js file to handle events I receive the below error.

[image: Error]

My app.js code snippet is below.

```
import React from "react";

import NavigationBar from "./Components/NavigationBar/NavigationBar.js";
import SideDrawer from "./Components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer.js";
import BackDrop from "./Components/BackDrop/BackDrop.js";

function App() {
  state = {
    sideDrawerOpen: False,
  };

  function drawerToggleClickHandler() {
    this.setState(function prevState() {
      return { sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen };
    });
  }

  render();
  {
    let sideDrawer = null;
    let backDrop = null;

    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      sideDrawer = <SideDrawer />;
      backDrop = <BackDrop />;
    };

    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <NavigationBar drawerToggleClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
        {sideDrawer}
        {backDrop}
        <main style={{ marginTop: "64px" }}>
          <p>This is the page content</p>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have been following the steps in detail and cannot find a solution to the problem.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

The YouTube video I have been watching is below for reference.

[Video resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6nmysZKHFU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has many syntax errors. It seems you're mixing class component syntax with function component syntax.

Since you're using  `this.setState()` this is definitely supposed to be a class component, it should look something like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sideDrawerOpen: false,
  };

  drawerToggleClickHandler() {
    this.setState(function prevState() {
      return {
        sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    let sideDrawer = null;
    let backDrop = null;

    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      sideDrawer = <SideDrawer/> ;
      backDrop = <BackDrop/> ;
    };

    return (
       <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <NavigationBar drawerToggleClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
        {sideDrawer}
        {backDrop}
        <main style={{ marginTop: "64px" }}>
          <p>This is the page content</p>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment, I didn't realise there were class components.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use function component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

import NavigationBar from "./Components/NavigationBar/NavigationBar.js";
import SideDrawer from "./Components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer.js";
import BackDrop from "./Components/BackDrop/BackDrop.js";

function App() {

const [state, setState] = useState({sideDrawerOpen: false})

  function drawerToggleClickHandler() {
    setState({ sideDrawerOpen: !state.sideDrawerOpen });
  }
let sideDrawer = null;
    let backDrop = null;

    if (state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      sideDrawer = <SideDrawer />;
      backDrop = <BackDrop />;
    };

    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <NavigationBar drawerToggleClickHandler={drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
        {sideDrawer}
        {backDrop}
        <main style={{ marginTop: "64px" }}>
          <p>This is the page content</p>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```